# Defining functions and classes in exec in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scope, exec

You can define both classes and functions in exec'd code without problems:

```
my_func = """
    def test_func():
        print "Hi from test_func!"
    """
my_class = """
    class test_class:
        def __init__(self):
            self.a = "a"
    """

def call_func():
    exec(my_func)
    test_func()

def call_class():
    exec(my_class)
    a = test_class()

>>> call_func()
Hi from test_func!

>>> call_class()
a
```

However, defining both a class and a function that uses that class in exec'd code results in a `NameError`, because the class doesn't end up in the correct scope:

```
my_class_fun = """
class test_class_2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "a"

def test_func_2():
    a = test_class_2()
    print(a.a)
"""

def test_2():
    exec(my_class_fun)
    test_func_2()

>>> test_2()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in test_2
  File "<string>", line 7, in test_func_2
NameError: global name 'test_class_2' is not defined
```

Passing `globals()` as the second argument to `exec` so that everything ends up in the global namespace fixes this problem.

My question is, why is that necessary? `test_class_2` and `test_func_2` seem like they should both be local to `test_2`, so why doesn't `test_func_2` have access to `test_class_2`?

EDIT:

Fundamentally, my question is why is `test_2()` above different from something like this code, which works fine:

```
def test_func():
   class test_class:
     def __init__(self):
       self.a = "a"
   def test_func_inner():
     c = test_class()
     print(c.a)
   test_func_inner()

>>> test_func()
a
```

Comment: The question I marked as duplicate uses slightly different exec-ed code, but I think the answer answers your question as well.  Please clarify your question if you think something remains unanswered.

Comment: That question uses Python 3, whereas I'm using 2.7. I know that the exec function works very differently in 3 (i.e. it's an actual function, whereas in 2 it's a statement), but I don't know if that changes the answer. It's entirely possible that the underlying mechanism that they're both getting at is the same.

Comment: The key point is that when globals and locals are different, "the code is executed as if it were embedded in a class definition", and that is [https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec](unchanged) in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Because your class (and function) not in global space

Demo:

```
>>> def test_2():
...     exec(my_class_fun)
...     global test_class_2
...     global test_func_2
...     test_func_2()
... 
>>> test_2()
a
```

Comment: Right, but my question is why do they need to be? Why isn't it good enough for them to both be local to test_2?

Comment: @seaotternerd because you run exec in local space of test_2 and test_func_2 don't know where get test_class_2, when we put test_class_2 in global space, then function test_func_2 know where get test_class_2